# Variable access Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to return the value of this variable `someobj`. Any thoughts much appreciated.

```js
getSomeObj: function () {
               let arr1 = ["abc", "def", "efh", "xys", "xus"]; 
               someobj = {};
               arr1.map((type) =>{
                // Gets the value from a promise as an array
                   this.getValuesOfSomeObj(type).then(function(vals){
                               (vals.map((val) =>{
                                   someobj[val.name] = val.name;
                                   someobj[val.title] = val.title; //I am getting value here
                             }));
                   });
               });
               return someobj; //I am not getting it here
           }
```

Comment: this.getValuesOfSomeObj(type).then((vals) => {
 use arrow function like this.

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @VLAZ- the function ```getValuesOfSomeObj returns a promise. I am just trying to consume it.

Comment: And you should do it *asynchronously*. It's not possible to turn async code into synchronous one.

Comment: @VLAZ - You are correct.